# How to represent a linestring using a point class

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to Implement a class for representing a linestring. I have a class called "Point" that 
represents a point with 2 coordinates and I want to use it for storing the internal vertices
of the linestring.
I came up with this piece of code:

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class LineString(Point):
    def __init__(self, point):
        self.point = point
```

but I don't know how to show multiple points in the linestring 
to support a linestring like:

```
lin = LineString((1, 1), (0, 2), (3,6))
```

I don't know the number of points that may appear in the linestring.
the new code:

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class LineString(Point):
    def __init(self, *points):
        #~ self.points=points
        self.points = []
        for point in points:
            if not isinstance(point, Point):
                point = Point(*point)
            self.points.append(point)

    def length(self):
        L = len(self.points)
        return L




if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Tests for LineString
    # ===================================
    lin1 = LineString((1, 1), (0, 2))
    assert len(lin1.points) == sqrt(2.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your constructor a variable-argument with `*argumentname`:

```
class LineString(Point):
    def __init__(self, *points):
        self.points = points
```

You can convert tuples to `Point()` instances as needed:

```
class LineString(Point):
    def __init__(self, *points):
        self.points = []
        for point in points:
            if not isinstance(point, Point):
                point = Point(*point)
            self.points.append(point)
```

In both cases `self.points` is now a Python `list` object. Note the use of the mirror syntax in the `Point(*point)` call; the elements of the `point` tuple are applied as separate arguments to the `Point.__init__()` method, passing in a `(1, 1)` tuple as two arguments for `x` and `y`.

Now you can build a line-string with either:

```
lin = LineString((1, 1), (0, 2), (3,6))
```

or

```
lin = LineString(Point(1, 1), Point(0, 2), Point(3,6))
```

Demo:

```
>>> lin = LineString((1, 1), (0, 2), (3,6))
>>> len(lin.points)
3
>>> lin.points[0]
<__main__.Point object at 0x108988fd0>
>>> lin.points[0].x, lin.points[0].y
(1, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I extract the length of the linestring for example?

Comment: For me it throws an error: LineString' object has no attribute 'points'

Comment: @f.ashouri: make sure you didn't mistype `self.points =` in your code.

Comment: @f.ashouri: Are you expecting to calculate the length of the line? Then you'd need to do more than just count the number of points in the list (which is what `len(self.points)` does).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45573/discussion-between-f-ashouri-and-martijn-pieters)

Answer (score 1):

Lines are not points, and neither are strings of lines. The [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) states that it should always be possible to substitute an instance of a derived class for one of its parent class. Consider this code:

```
def move_point(point, xdist, ydist):
    return Point(point.x + xdist, point.y + ydist)

p = Point(3, 4)
q = move_point(p, 5, 6)
assert q.x == 8 and q.y == 10

r = LineString((2, 3), (5, 4), (8, 6))
s = move_point(r, 5, 6)  # ???
```

What could `s` possibly be? What would be the `(x, y)` coordinate of a String of Lines?

The solution to this is simply to not derive LineString from Point. Instead, the code should look something like this:

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    ...  # see implementation details @ http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#recipes

class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

def distance(point1, point2):
    ...  # needs implementing

class Line(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):  # a and b must be Points
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    @property
    def length(self):
        return distance(self.a, self.b)

class LineString(object):
    def __init(self, *points):
        # We assume that points consists only of proper Point instances.
        # If people pass invalid arguments, it's their problem.
        self.points = points

    @property
    def length(self):
        return sum(distance(p1, p2) for p1, p2 in pairwise(self.points))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lin1 = LineString((1, 1), (0, 2))
    assert lin1.length == sqrt(2.0)
```

Also, floating point arithmetic sometimes produces strange results:

```
>>> .1 + .2 == .3
False
>>> .1 + .2
0.30000000000000004
```

For an explanation, please see http://floating-point-gui.de.